# how do I align my red div element to the top of my button?

Tags: html, css

how do I align my red div element to the top of my button? I have tried to use `position: absolute; top: 0;` but that just aligns my red div to the top of the page, not the top of the button. originally, I was using a picture not a red div but since I'm running it in a code snippet I can't use the picture.

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

button {
    transition: transform 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    color: none;
}


button:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}

div {
    width: 310px;
    height: 170px; 
    background: red;
    background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>shop.shop</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action="https://netflix.com/" target="_blank">
        <button type="submit">
            <div>

            </div>
            <!---p>visit netflix and stuff </p>-->
        </button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the color red is in the top of the button, what exactly you need? could you brief about the requirement some more?

Comment: @Manjuboyz its ok, it's fixed but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to control the positioning of child elements, the parent is given a position property. Often the element is given a`position:relative`.
This allows for the child element to be positioned absolute and forced into a position.

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
```

There are other ways to accomplish it with flexbox. I often us this link as reference:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

button {
    transition: transform 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    color: none;
    position:relative;
}


button:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}

div {
    width: 310px;
    height: 170px; 
    background: red;
    background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>shop.shop</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action="https://netflix.com/" target="_blank">
        <button type="submit">
            <div>

            </div>
            <!---p>visit netflix and stuff </p>-->
        </button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```